# NPM Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: npm

After updated Node (upto v8.6.0) and npm (upto v5.5.1) I cannot execute command `npm install`.
After npm install I've error message:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

What's trouble or I need downgrade node/npm ?

Comment: I've downgraded npm to 4.6.1

Comment: @nocarrier try out my solution

Comment: you should downgrade the npm 5.2.0 or less. updates has a bug or something for windows 10.

Comment: @Dmitrii Did any of these solutions work for you? If so can you choose one as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I've made some tests:

nodejs@8.6.0 npm@5.5.1  - I have trouble and the test fails

```
nvm use 8.5.0
```

nodejs@8.5.0 npm@5.5.1 - I have trouble and the test fails

```
nvm use 8.4.0
```

nodejs@8.4.0 npm@5.5.1 - I have trouble and the test fails

```
npm install npm@^5 -g
```

nodejs@8.4.0 npm@5.4.2 - I have trouble and the test fails

```
nvm use 8.6.0
npm install npm@^4 -g
```

nodejs@8.6.0 npm@4.6.1 - no trouble, this fixes it.

Answer (score 64):

I had the same problem.

I removed both **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** and then did:

```
npm install
```

And it worked.

Edit by [@OwlyMoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8432239/owlymoly)
Due to new updates and the restriction to old dependencies in package-lock.json is causing this conflicts. By doing `npm install` won't fix this issue. Instead by ditching npm_modules and package-lock.json and doing `npm install` will load a new node_modules and that supposed to be required by package.json. You have to commit the new package-lock.json along with your latest changes of the project.

Comment: Removing cache `npm cache clear --force` also helps, before running these steps.

Comment: This solution work for me. I lose 2h to find this. When I remove node_modules it was to little. I reinstall Node, NPM and all times I had errors...

Comment: Can confirm `npm cache clear --force` can do something that helps. I had a 'bluebird' related error that was closest to the `property 0 of undefined` message.

Comment: Removing package-lock.json was enough in my case, it didn't get to the step of creating a node_modules directory

Answer (score 7):

Do 2 steps bellow (Window):

`rm -rf ./node_modules` to remove node folder

`rm package-lock.json` to remove `package-lock.json` file

then `npm install` to re-install the node modules

Answer (score 4):

Just download and install latest [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) which is also a node package manager, developed by facebook, ***but has a much better dependency management***. Also update your [node cli](https://nodejs.org/en/) (optional).

And then, install your dependencies using `yarn`:

```
yarn install
```

or

```
yarn // short version of yarn install
```

No errors!

You can continue to use `npm` after you have installed all dependencies with `yarn` or continue with `yarn`....it's your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with a combination of factors.

Some workarounds here:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18238

Answer (score 1):

npm 5.3.0 is broken for **windows 10** after upgrading the nodeJS.
You should downgrade the npm, it is a temporary solution but works fine.

`npm install -g npm@5.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

For me (npm@6.9.0) solved the issue by deleting `node_modules` and performing `npm install`, but without removing `package.json.lock` file.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run: `npm install`

**or**

Just run: `npm install -g npm@latest` to upgrade it to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Try with nvm(Node Version Manager).it help you to install any node version for any project without any Error.

Comment: I've tried some node version (8.5 and 8.4). It's not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem when using npm version 5.5.1 to install **babel-preset-stage-0**

**Solution:**
I downgraded npm to version 5.2.0 and try to install again then it can solve the issue.

```
npm i -g npm@5.2.0    
npm i -D babel-preset-stage-0
```

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this issue using `nvs` (Node Version Switcher -  https://github.com/jasongin/nvs) `node@10.15.3` and `npm@6.9.0`. The reason was a local package I had linked with `npm link`. The solution was to remove that folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case reinstalling `node_modules` have not fixed this issue.
Problem was with one `*.ts` file which was missing in source codes.
Do not know why It was not displaying compilation error, but adding this missing file to repository solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading npm to version `7.5.4` did the job for me.

```sh
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
`npm ci`

> Install a project with a clean slate
> docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci

Deletes `node_modules` and installs everything based on `package-lock.json`, so no need to regenerate that

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error caused by trying to operate on a `lockfileversion 3` file using `npm@6.14.13` and `node@v14.17.3`.

Simply upgrading these two solved it.