# VSTS Build Fails With Error: Set-Content : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\1\a\Publish\manifest.xml'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am completely new to VSTS and am working my way through the Microsoft Parts Unlimited GitHub Guide here: https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/pandp/200.1x-PandP-CICDQuickstartwithVSTS.html

The build of the project successfully completes on my machine without any issues.  The build task is a PowerShell 'dotnet restore, build, test and publish' task.  I tried using Version 2.0 instead of 1.0 but it still fails (with a slightly different error).

I've followed all the instructions in the guide and the build is failing with the error:

> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.   Restoring
>   packages for
>   d:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimitedWebSite\PartsUnlimitedWebsite.csproj...
>   Restore completed in 81.65 ms for
>   d:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimited.Models\PartsUnlimited.Models.csproj.
>   Restore completed in 18.55 ms for
>   d:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimitedWebSite\PartsUnlimitedWebsite.csproj.
>   Restore completed in 29.21 ms for
>   d:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimitedWebSite\PartsUnlimitedWebsite.csproj.
>   Generating MSBuild file
>   d:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimitedWebSite\obj\PartsUnlimitedWebsite.csproj.nuget.g.props.
>   Restore completed in 688.66 ms for
>   d:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimitedWebSite\PartsUnlimitedWebsite.csproj.
>   npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR! C:\npm\cache_logs\2018-02-01T22_41_03_591Z-debug.log
>
> d:\a\1\s\src\PartsUnlimitedWebSite\PartsUnlimitedWebsite.csproj(39,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "npm install --loglevel=error" exited with
>   code 1.
>
> Set-Content : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\1\a\Publish\manifest.xml'.
>
> Process completed with exit code 1 and had 2 error(s) written to the error stream.

Where can I even begin to figure out what is causing this?

Comment: There are some things to try here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46998780/7034621

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true)

Comment: @orhtej2 I don't know how you were able to deduce what the problem is but the information in the post you linked provided my answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @vhusker if you take a look at your output you can see there's a `npm ERR!` before the one you pointed out. Rule of the thumb is to solve problems starting from the first one, and quick SO search revealed the thread linked. Glad I could help!

Comment: @vhusker Do you mean the issue has been solved?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT yes, the issue has been resolved