# npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

```
λ npm i
npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I checked all similar questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619949/npm-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined) and many more. So far, what I have tried:

1. delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`, then `npm i`
2. repeat removal of folder and file in step 1 + clear the cache with `npm cache clear --force`
3. `nvm uninstall 10.13.0`, reinstall the version
4. uninstall nvm and reinstall nvm

In between, I rebooted my PC several times. Downgrading my Node version is not an option as I am working on a company project.

Here is my NPM log:

```
3782 silly saveTree `-- websocket@1.0.29 3783 verbose stack TypeError:
 Cannot read property '0' of undefined 3783 verbose stack     at
 rmStuff (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\lib\unbuild.js:61:24)
 3783 verbose stack     at tryCatcher
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
 3783 verbose stack     at ret (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promisify.js:184:12),
 <anonymous>:13:39) 3783 verbose stack     at lifecycle.then.then
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\unbuild.js:12:12)
 3783 verbose stack     at tryCatcher
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
 3783 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
 3783 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
 3783 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
 3783 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
 3783 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill
 (C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
 3783 verbose stack     at
 C:\tools\nvm\v10.13.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\nodeback.js:42:21
 3784 verbose cwd C:\src\agl-bot-alfie\botkit 3785 verbose Windows_NT
10.0.17134 3786 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
 3787 verbose node v10.13.0 3788 verbose npm  v6.4.1 3789 error Cannot
 read property '0' of undefined 3790 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Use the correct version of npm and node.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct version of npm and node. You can use a `nvm` https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Check the package.json value. For example:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "~6.17.1",
  "npm": ">=5.0.0"
}
```